# X = x + 1 in Mac terminal

Tags: mac, bash, terminal

How do I assign x the value of x + 1? I can do it in other languages but can't figure it out in bash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just tested two different ways and both worked for me:

```
x=$((x+1))
```

...or...

```
x=$((++x))
```

Answer (score 3):

this should do the work

```
let x=$x+1
```

Comment: That gets a return of 1.

Comment: `let x=x+1` should be `let x=$x+1`.  That is likely the reason it is returning one.

Comment: oops, missed the dollar

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
x = `expr $x + 1`
```

Comment: Nope. It assigns what's in the quote to x.

Comment: @JShoe:  Those weren't quotes, they were [grave accents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent).  On most keyboards, they're located to the left of the `1` key, on the key you press with `Shift` to enter a tilde (`~`).

Comment: Also known as backticks in the context of computing.

Comment: Another reason not to use backticks anymore, but rather `$()` ;)

Comment: Though a valid answer, `expr` is old school. It makes you shell out, an unnecessary process. The syntax in @Bandit 's answer is more modern, and is done in-shell.

Answer (score 0):

@Bandit's answer is fine, but I want to highlight the difference that "let" and (( )) make to normal shell syntax:

```
let x++
```

causes bash (or ksh, or any POSIX shell) to treat the expression as an "arithmetic evaluation" in which the referenced variables don't need to be preceeded with "$". One advantage of using (( )) is that otherwise-special tokens don't need to be quoted or escaped, e.g. "*" for multiplication as in:

```
(( x = x * 2 ))
```

I find this syntax slightly clearer than $(( )) which uses the output of the expression, e.g.

```
x=$(( x * 2 ))
```